# How to associate a python program to a download link within a browser and get information from it

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple mod manager which uses the nexus website to download the mod. When on the website, there is an option to download a given mod as a file or via a mod manager, the latter being an "nxm" link. I figured out how to associate a program with the nxm link through registry editor, but now I don't know how to get any information from that link within the python program. Is there a module that will do it? Essentially, I want to know how to open a python program via a link and have the link as an object which I can use in the program.

Comment: use selenium webdriver or requests

Answer (score 0):

Try using py-script and javascript alongside.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).